# Is It possible get a connection string from other app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have two website application,

first Application is located at:

```
MyApp/WebApp1
```

and the second at:

```
MyApp/WebApp2
```

is it possible WebApp2 get a Connection String from WebApp1 web.config?

Comment: If you have full trust, you should be able to extract it from the other web.config file - it's just xml..

Comment: you can read anything on disk - but you need to have permission for that ! From one application to the other if you have permission and know the exactly directory you can read it and get the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Terry you can expose a WS or 
You can put another web.config in MyApp folder Framework will parse the hirearachy and get the entry from partent folder.

Here is the link if you wana know about configuration resolution

[Config Hirearchy](http://blogs.iis.net/tomwoolums/archive/2008/12/15/configuration-store-hierarchy.aspx)

Comment: how do I retrieve an entry from the parent web.config?
for example MyApp/WebApp2
can I retrieve something from web.config in MyApp?

Comment: Yes you can, you need not do anything special. Just access the config entry like its in your WebApp2 folder. .NET Framework will take care of getting it from parent folder.

Comment: ok..I get it, another question,
is it possible if I mixing web form application with MVC..
for example I have web form application at WebFormApp/,
and I want to put my MVC Application in WebFormApp/MVCApp Folder

Comment: Never tried that but should be possible as the the configuration framewkr only cares of Web.config. Tt dosnet matter if there is a MVC app in that folder or if its empty, As long as the entries are relevant and cane be read and used.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible, you may read put it in file accesible to both project and read it from there

Answer (score 1):

You can create and publish a webservice in first website which provider related required

information in IIS, And the another website can access it by webservice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by saving the connection string in a common place in a website where both of these application have access..

Like keep it in a folder in a normal text file and then read the connection string. This is the easiest way.